# Sentence of Hot water Caution

Tags: phrase-request

I need to write a caution notice on notice board to ask people to *be cautious when they turn the faucet level to the left end, that will be burning.*

But my concern is the above sentence is too long for a sign (*and not cool*
). Could it be conciser?

Comment: You may put 'extreme hot' on the left side of the lever or whatever. And yes, to convey this message, you may need to put sign of 'hot' on the middle and right side of the faucet.

Answer (score 5):

A caution sign should be short or people may not bother to read it.  The signs I see above hot taps normally just say, "Caution! Very hot water."

[image: Caution! Very hot water]

Comment: Is this the answer? Very hot water comes only when the lever is turned extreme left. The sign is misguiding